# How to display the :after content outside element

Tags: html, css

In the following case, how can I make it such that the text generated by the `:after` is outside the box of the span? (It currently is rendered inside, i.e. it makes the `span` element wider)

HTML

```
<span class="my">Boxtext</span>
```

CSS

```
span.my {
    padding:            4px 8px;
    background-color:   red;
    display:            inline-block;
    border-radius:      10px;
    margin-left:        20px;
    }   
span.my:after {
    content:            " text that is supposed to come after the box";
    }
```

I guess this is somewhat similar to list-style-position, where you can chose inside or outside...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe CSS content is considered part of the object against which it was rendered. You could make the argument that `:after` should have been named `:append`.

For your case you can try putting an extra element inside `span.my`:

```
<span class="my"><span>Boxtext</span></span>
span.my span { ... }
span.my:after { ... }
```

Or styling the content specifically.

```
span.my:after { 
    content:            " text that is supposed to come after the box";
    background-color:   white;
    position:           absolute;
    margin-left:        10px;
}
```

Comment: Thx, but the second solution will look unpleasant due to, as you mentioned, the border (-radius). For the first solution, I guess that would work, but I was looking for a solution that works with my original html.

Comment: After looking at this answer, I hacked up this example: http://jsfiddle.net/cawgZ/

Comment: Using absolute positioning, you can make the second solution look better. http://jsbin.com/ibuqip

Comment: @Ben, You'll probably have to explicitly specify your widths to overcome that.

Comment: I'm gonna go with solution 1. Thx.

Answer (score 7):

Just use `position: absolute` in the `::after {}` pseudo-element's css:

```
span.my:after {
    content: " text that is supposed to come after the box";
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
}​
```

Remember, of course, to use `position: relative;` (or any other `position` value) on the parent `span.my` element.

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PMFst/).

Also remember that as the `::after` (and the `::before`) pseudo-element inherits from the span to which it's 'attached' that it'll inherit the `width`, so that may need to be explicitly overridden in the CSS for that/those elements.